# Google App Engine blocks multipart/form-data post request due to CORS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, axios, cors

I am trying to set up a post request using Axios that transfer **multipart/form-data content** from the frontend "frontend.com" to a backend server hosted on Google App Engine "backend.com". However, the post request fails due to:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'backend.com/uploadImages' from origin 'frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is my frontend React code:

```
const { data } = await axios.post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/uploadImages`,
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
            },
          },
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
```

Here is my CORS configuration in NodeJS:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

**Note:**

- The same code works when I do a post request from "frontend.com" to "backend.onrender.com", where "backend.onrender.com" is the domain of the backend deployment in Render...Hence why I suspect the problem has to do with my deployment to Google App Engine.
- Post request that only involves json content works fine.

I know that handlers in the app.yaml file do CORS support for Google App Engine...but I'm not exactly sure how to set those up, or if that's even the problem...

Please help if you know what the issue is!

Comment: can you have a look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368876/cors-policy-blocking-my-api-requests-in-a-google-cloud-platform-app-engine-in-a)

Comment: That solution unfortunately does not work....got the exact same error message even after I used that code